# Array as constructor parameter

Tags: java

I Have a problem . I am learning java and this sample code is not working, saying :

```
 $javac Quicksort.java 2>&1
    Quicksort.java:16: error: constructor Quicksort in class Quicksort cannot be applied to given types;
    Quicksort qc = new Quicksort(values);
    ^
    required: no arguments
    found: int[]
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    1 error
```

Not able to figure out why . Can anyone help ??

My code snippet is :

```
   public class Quicksort{
   public int[] number ;

   public void Quicksort(int[] values){
       this.number=values;
   }
   public void print(){
       for (int i=0; i<number.length;i++)
           System.out.println(number[i]);



   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
       int[] values = {3,4,5,6,7,8};
       Quicksort qc = new Quicksort(values);
       qc.print();
   }

}
```

Comment: This is not how you define the constructor in Java - you defined a simple method, not a constructor. As a result your code simply assumes the default no-argument one.

Comment: the constructor return type shouldn't be specified, the compiler know what is the return type of constructor and its not a void but a object of a class that it constructs

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your definition of `Constructor` is incorrect.

```
 public void Quicksort(int[] values){
       this.number=values;
   }
```

Should be

```
 public  Quicksort(int[] values){
       this.number=values;
   }
```

constructor wont have a return type.

[Providing Constructors for Your Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint. Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type.

For example, `Bicycle` has one constructor:

```
public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
    gear = startGear;
    cadence = startCadence;
    speed = startSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void Quicksort(int[] values){
       this.number=values;
 }
```

should be

```
public Quicksort(int[] values){
       this.number=values;
}
```

Your constructor should not have a return type (in your case `void`). Otherwise it will be considered as a method

Comment: Try to use an IDE like eclipse for "learning" Java. Most IDEs would either give a warning like "Warning: method defined with Constructor name/signature" or are even able to flag this as an error. (Can be configured in "compiler settings")